# In Silverlight HttpWebRequest does not contain definition for GetResponse()

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am working on SL4 and when I run following code it gives me the error as

> HttpWebRequest does not contain definition for GetResponse().

Then how to get the response.

```
string str = "http://sam.com/getdeatils.php";

HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(str);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
string end = stream Reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

It s because silverlight work asyncrously have at rest sharp. Hope it help